# "Have you seen him recently?" or "Did you see him recently?"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> Have you seen him recently?

or

> Did you see him recently?

Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct but are used in different contexts.

If John is visiting this country I might ask someone, "Have you seen him recently?"
If John is no longer in this country I might ask, "Did you see him recently?"

In the first question, seeing John is still possible. In the second, the opportunity has gone.

If someone has recently died it would sound very odd to ask a friend of his, "Have you seen him recently?" though you could ask, "Did you see him recently?"

At - or soon after - lunchtime you might ask your friend, "Have you had lunch?" A few hours later, when lunch is no longer available, you would ask, "Did you have lunch?"

Comment: 'Did you see him recently?' is also possible as an alternative for 'Have you seen him recently?' in a pointed follow-up question, say in a police investigation.

Comment: Your answer is great, but some ESL students might find it misleading – let me point out that there are many contexts where both forms are possible (these are those contexts where the two possible meanings overlap).